# How to do search with out using the scripting language and by using jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a html site. In that site around 100 html files are available. i want to develop the search engine . If the user typing any word and enter search then i want to display the related contents with the keyword. Is't possible to do without using any server side scripting? And it's possible to implement by using jquery or javascript?? Please let me know if you have any ideas!!!

Advance thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Possible? Yes. You can download all the files via AJAX, save their contents in an array of strings, and search the array.

The performance however would be dreadful. If you need full text search, then for any decent performance you will need a database and a special fulltext search engine.

Comment: @Mayilarun - I'd strongly recommend against it. The result will be practically unusable.

Comment: i plan to save the content in one javascript file. Then in every page i'll show the content from javascript. When the user press the search button i'll hide the content div and showing the search result. using the jquery function we can implement this idea. I'm not sure about this whether it will give best result or not. Please give the feedback on this plan..

Comment: Just to reinforce this, Vilx- is mentioning that you could do this, but it would be a very bad idea. Don't do it this way. Use a database + serverside scripting. It's the only real way! Otherwise your users will have to download your whole site to query it. Not a good plan!

Comment: If you have 100 pages, surely the javascript file will be huge?

Comment: yes you are correct !! the problem is, client is not ready to purchase the new space in the server. Presently it's supporting only html. That's y i have to implement without db.

Comment: This is getting a bit off-topic, but you shouldn't need to purchase new space in order to activate a PHP/Perl/JSP/ASP module in your current webserver...

Comment: @Mayilarun - Then better tell your client that you cannot implement this in any reasonable fashion without a DB. Honestly. It's not the javascript speed - it's the full website download that will take the time, even on broadband. Well... I suppose you could generate some kind of (javascript-ish) index offline and then load just that... perhaps partition it and load just the relevant part when searching... but the amount of work to implement this would cost way more than extra space on the server. If not, then he REALLY needs to find a better hosting service.

Comment: Oh, and [Ergo's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155209/how-to-do-search-with-out-using-the-scripting-language-and-by-using-jquery/4155272#4155272) for using google also is a win. Perhaps that's even the best one.

Answer (score 2):

3 means:

1. Series of Ajax indexing requests: very slow, not recommended
2. Use a DB to store key terms/page refernces and perform a fulltext search
3. Utilise off the shelf functionality, such as that offered by google

Answer (score 2):

The only way this can work is if you have a list of all the pages on the page you are searching from. So you could do this:

```
pages = new Array("page1.htm","page2.htm"...)
```

and so on. The problem with that is that to search for the results, the browser would need to do a GET request for every page:

```
for (var i in pages)
  $.get(pages[i], function (result) { searchThisPage(result) });
```

Doing that 100 times would mean a long wait for the user. Another way I can think of is to have all the content served in an array:

```
pages = {
  "index" : "Some content for the index",
  "second_page" : "Some content for the second page",
  etc...
}
```

Then each page could reference this one script to get all the content, include the content for itself in its own content section, and use the rest for searching. If you have a lot of data, this would be a lot to load in one go when the user first arrives at your site.

The final option I can think of is to use the Google search API: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply - no.

Client-side javascript runs in the client's browser.  The client does not have any way to know about the contents of the documents within your domain.  If you want to do a search, you'll need to do it server-side and then return the appropriate HTML to the client.

The only way to technically do this client-side would be to send the client all the data about all of the documents, and then get them to do the searching via some JS function.  And that's ridiculously inefficient, such that there is no excuse for getting them to do so when it's easier, lighter-weight and more efficient to simply maintain a search database on the server (likely through some nicely-packaged third party library) and use that.

Answer (score 0):

some useful resources

http://johnmc.co/llum/how-to-build-search-into-your-site-with-jquery-and-yahoo/

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/09/google-powered-site-search-ajax-jquery/

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/gss

Answer (score 0):

If your site is allowing search engine indexing, then fcalderan's approach is definitely the simplest approach.

If not, it is possible to generate a text file that serves as an index of the HTML files. This would probably be rudimentarily successful, but it is possible. You could use something like the keywording in [Toby Segaran's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325) to build a JSON text file. Then, use jQuery to load up the text file and find the instances of the keywords, unique the resultant filenames and display the results.